# Why does casting a Python dict to a tuple return a tuple of keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, casting

I came across some Python code that had me very confused.

```
my_dict = {'a': 'b'}
a, = my_dict            # a = 'a'
a, b = my_dict          # ValueError: Too many values to unpack
```

Basically, I found that casting a dictionary as a tuple returns a tuple of the dictionary's keys.

```
my_dict = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
a = tuple(my_dict)      # a = ('a', 'c')
```

Why does a tuple(dict) return a tuple of keys? I can make sense of it, but wasn't able to find any documentation or explanation around why. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: When you loop over a dictionary, by default, you are looping over its keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary objects are clearly documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> iter(d)
>
> Return an iterator over the keys of the dictionary.

Note, this is why I don't like using the term "cast" when you use `list` or `tuple` to convert *an iterable* into a list or tuple. And from the tuple [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple):

> class tuple([iterable]):
>
> ...
>
> The constructor builds a `tuple` whose items are the same and in the
>   same order as *iterable*’s items. *iterable* may be either a sequence,
>   a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If
>   *iterable* is already a tuple, it is returned unchanged. For example, `tuple('abc')` returns `('a', 'b', 'c')` and `tuple( [1, 2, 3] )`
>   returns `(1, 2, 3)`. If no argument is given, the constructor creates
>   a new empty tuple, `()`.